# How do I tell Android Studio to use GCC 4.9 with CMake?

Tags: android, c++, gradle, android-ndk, cmake

I'm using NDK r12 with Android Studio 2.2. I need CMake to use GCC 4.9 instead of Clang to build our code base, however even if I provide the following it still uses clang:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 17

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc-4.9'
                cppFlags "-std=c++14 -fexceptions -frtti"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried `-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc` as well but this doesn't work either. How can I get CMake to use GCC ARM toolchain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split your `arguments` string into one string per argument:

```
arguments '-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF','-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc'
```

I don't know if it's possible to explicitly specify version 4.9 of GCC ("gcc-4.9" didn't work). However, that's redundant anyway since GCC 4.8 was removed in NDK r11, so GCC 4.9 is now the only version of GCC included in the NDK, and `ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc` therefore implicitly means GCC 4.9.

Comment: wow so this has to be done differently than the list of options in `cppFlags`? Who the hell is designing this stuff...

Comment: Well, `cppFlags` [is also supposed to be](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions:cppFlags) a `List<String>`. Maybe it still works with just one long string with a bunch of flags in it, but it doesn't appear to work with `arguments`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that it's impossible now and GCC toolchaing is dropped.

I get this error when trying to set `ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc`:

CMake Error at D:/Android/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:169 (message):
  GCC is no longer supported.  See
  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/ClangMigration.md