# Android Studio C++ optimization parameters performance

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, android-studio

Why do I have different performance between VS Android with Eclipse & Android Studio for the same function and hardware?

I need to use the following additional compiler options:

`-std=c++11  -fexceptions -mtune=arm7 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp`

to tune my library. Before I used VS Android with GCC:

[image]

Those parameters where defined in the C++ Command Line Additional Options in the project config, see image below:

[image]

Then I migrated my project to Android Studio and now I am trying to configure the same compiler options in the following places:

**Build.gradle:**

[image]

**Cmake:**

[image]

But the performance of the libraries compiled in VS android & the libraries compiled in Android Studio differ. For example, execution time of function A in a VS Android compiled library takes 0.047 sec and in Android Studio the same function A takes 0.135 sec

Comment: Try enabling optimizations: `-O3`

Comment: are you sure you have used the same toolchain? in VS you seem to be using gcc4.9, in AndroidStudio you seem to be using default toolchain which really depends on the ndk version you are using, it very well may be clang and then its obvious that results may differ

Comment: @OlegBogdanov , it's seems like gcc4.9 is the default http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243009/how-do-i-tell-android-studio-to-use-gcc-4-9-with-cmake

Comment: @Nimrod Borochov again, it depends on ndk ver