# How to use NDK wth gcc on Android?

Tags: gcc, cmake, android-ndk

I need to compile OpenCV 2 to test some things and it can only be built with gcc. I tried downloading the oldest NDK in Android Studio which is version 16, however it still tries to use clang. How can I force it to use gcc?

Error on version 16:

```
ERROR: /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/opencv2builder/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt : C/C++ debug|x86 : CMake Error at /home/user/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/16.1.4479499/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/opencv2builder/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command:"/home/user/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja" "cmTC_ed369"
    [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_ed369.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_ed369.dir/testCCompiler.c.o 
    /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/16.1.4479499/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --target=i686-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/16.1.4479499/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/16.1.4479499/sysroot   -isystem /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/16.1.4479499/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -fPIE -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_ed369.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c testCCompiler.c
    /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/16.1.4479499/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt
Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243009/how-do-i-tell-android-studio-to-use-gcc-4-9-with-cmake

Comment: This is a case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). I don't think you NEED gcc. The error is that it cannot find the ncurses library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005654/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libncurses-so-5)